# bootstrap how to exclude style on certain element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage using a bootstrap theme. For one specifik control, in this case a select, i would like to exclude the style. How can i do this?

```
<select class="form-control" id="SelectNoStyle">
</select>
```

Comment: Exclude which style? If you don't want it to look like a bootstrap control just remove the `form-control` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it easily.You just have to remove bootstrap classes like form-control, from-label etc

```
<select id="SelectNoStyle">
</select>
```

Comment: In nested content, with plugins auto-injecting elements, this is not a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

To change anything in bootstrap styling, just add classes or element you want to change in your own css and it will override bootstrap. Just make sure your css is linked after bootstrap css.
Form elements in bootstrap are styled from forms.less (need to have [bootstrap source files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)), so find anything related to select in that file, copy to your css file and replace whatever you like or just remove form control class.

Bootstrap style from forms.less:

```
     .form-control {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: @input-height-base; // Make inputs at least the height of their button counterpart (base line-height + padding + border)
      padding: @padding-base-vertical @padding-base-horizontal;
      font-size: @font-size-base;
      line-height: @line-height-base;
      color: @input-color;
      background-color: @input-bg;
      background-image: none; // Reset unusual Firefox-on-Android default style; see https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/214
      border: 1px solid @input-border;
      border-radius: @input-border-radius;
      .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075));
}
```

Your css:

```
.form-control {
color:#5bc0de;
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add a code example of an overridden property, to make it as clear as possible how this is done?